# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=0 index=1. Store Androjena(jena for android) SPARQL queries in an array

Tags: java, exception, multidimensional-array, sparql, jena

The code bellow is a part of an activity of an Android app. I am using Jena(Androjena) to query rdf files. That part works fine. The problem is that i am trying to iterate through the results and store the in a two-dimensional array. Where the columns and rows should be like:

```
/////////////////
Adam /Sandler/43
Kate /Sandler/22  
Mike /Jasonss/13   
/////////////////
```

Code:

```
enter code here

// Query uses an external SPARQL endpoint for processing
            // This is the syntax for that type of query
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEndpointUri, query);

        // Execute the query and obtain results
        ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();

        // Setup a place to house results for output
        StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();

        // Get the column names (the aliases supplied in the SELECT clause)
        List<String> columnNames = resultSet.getResultVars();
        int i=0;
        int j=0;

        String results1[][] = new String[i][j];


   // Iterate through all resulting rows

        while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
            // Get the next result row
            QuerySolution solution = resultSet.next();

            results1  = new String[i][columnNames.size()];
            // Iterate through the columns
            for (String var : columnNames) {

                // Add the column label to the StringBuffer
                results.append(var + ": ");

                // Add the returned row/column data to the StringBuffer

                // Data value will be null if optional and not present
                if (solution.get(var) == null) {
                    results.append("{null}");
                // Test whether the returned value is a literal value
                } else if (solution.get(var).isLiteral()) {
                    results.append(solution.getLiteral(var).toString());

                    results1[resultSet.getRowNumber()][j]=solution.getLiteral(var).toString();
                    j++;
                // Otherwise the returned value is a URI
                } else {
                    results.append(solution.getResource(var).getURI().toString());

                    results1[resultSet.getRowNumber()][j]=solution.getResource(var).getURI().toString();
                    j++;
                }
                results.append('\n');

            }
            results.append("-----------------\n");
            i++;
        }
```

PS. Ignore the string buffer.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not know in advance the size of the result set, you cannot use an array.  Use an `ArrayList<String[]>` instead and add `String[]` elements to the list as you read rows from the resultSet.

```
ArrayList<String[]> results1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you have read all the rows you can still refer to the rows and columns by index if you want, using

```
results1.get(index)[colIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the array that you create is actually `String results1[][] = new String[i][j];` which is `String results1[][] = new String[0][columnNames.size()];`

Then in the `for (String var : columnNames)` loop you increment the value of i and try to set an element to `results1[resultSet.getRowNumber()][j]`.

Above you say its a `0,columnNames.size()` array and in the loop you try to access `resultSet.getRowNumber(), j`. `j` is legal here however `resultSet.getRowNumber()` is not.

Comment: I have change it to
  results1  = new String[i+1][columnNames.size()+1];and i get an exception on length=7..